# Which is the song Kanako (Meruru) sings?

Tags: music, oreimo

In *Oreimo 2* Episode 15, Meruru sings a song with the line "Red, blue and yellow, magic of many colors". I can't find the title of the song. It sounds amazing! Does anyone know it?

Answer (score 4):

That song seems to be called "Planet ☆ Burst", "Planet ☆ Bust", or "Planet ☆ Buster". Here's the screenshot from the ending credits where I got that name.

[image: Ending credits screenshot]

The hiragana say "Puranetto ☆ Baasuto". It's not clear to me exactly what the second word is supposed to be. My first thought was either "burst" or "bust", but I found [a Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/anime/comments/1znbup/looking_to_id_a_song_from_oreimo/) that refers to the song as "Planet ☆ Buster". This is also the name given on [the Youtube video of the song](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2Qd7LXwCPS8) linked by the Reddit thread. However, I would have expected "Planet ☆ Buster" to be written "Puranetto ☆ Basutaa" in hiragana.

Kanako is singing this song in Episode 15 when Kyousuke enters the concert hall, just before she confesses her love to him.

[image: Kanako singing]
[image: Kanako confessing her love]